# Simple finding the PDF given function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am a little confused on how to go about finding the PDF given a condition for a function.
So I have the function 
$$
Y(x)=ae^{-bx} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, a,b,x \geq0
$$
and I need to find the value for X (lets say X is some distance) given that it covers 80% of Y.

My understanding is that the summation of all the values of a probability density function is 1, so I thought to integrate the function to 0.8 then solve for X. Am I on the right track?
$$
Y (x)=\int_0^{0.8} ae^{-bx} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, a,b,x \geq0
$$

Answer (score 0):

No you have made a mistake. Covering 80% of Y(x) means : 0.8 (Total of Y)= 0.8(1).

It does not mean the upper value of the integral is 0.8, It means the total integral from 0 to some unknown value ($x$) is 0.8.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^x ae^{-bx}=0.8\end{align}$$

The objective is to find x now.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a few missteps:

1. The domain of integration is over the entire interval $[0, \infty)$, and the integral over that interval should be 1: 
   $$
   \int_0^\infty a e^{-b x} dx = 1.
   $$
2. You want to find where $80\%$ of the domain is covered, so you want to find $x_0$ such that 
   $$
   \int_0^{x_0} a e^{-b x} dx = 0.8. 
   $$
   Does that make sense?

Comment: yes! Thank you so much you!